# Play video from Download URL

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a URL :- "http://fitnation.theclientdemos.com:9000/media/uploads/videoplayback_3_JtVCHi1"
When I run this URL on browser, My VDO starts downloads.

Please help to play this video in a view (let view name is:- vdoView)

For this I am trying below code:-

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var vdoView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        getVideo()
    }

    func getVideo(){

        let videoURL = URL(string: "http://fitnation.theclientdemos.com:9000/media/uploads/videoplayback_3_JtVCHi1")

        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.vdoView.bounds
        self.vdoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226532/how-to-play-video-inside-a-uiview-without-controls-like-a-background-wallpaper) ?

Comment: according to your code, you forgot to `layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill`

Comment: @mustafa where should I add this code?

Comment: Yes I also check the thread , it plays the already saved videos , In my case I am playing through the link

Answer (score 4):

First you have to  **`import AVKit, import AVFoundation`**

**Using AVPlayer**

```
  if let url = URL(string: "http://fitnation.theclientdemos.com:9000/media/uploads/videoplayback_3_JtVCHi1"){

            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            let controller=AVPlayerViewController()
            controller.player=player
            controller.view.frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
            self.addChildViewController(controller)
            player.play()
        }
```

It's better to put this code into the method: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) or somewhere after.

Answer (score 3):

```
override func viewDidLoad()

    {
       let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://fitnation.theclientdemos.com:9000/media/uploads/videoplayback_3_JtVCHi1")
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try it like this

```
func getVideo(){

    let videoURL = URL(string: "http://fitnation.theclientdemos.com:9000/media/uploads/videoplayback_3_JtVCHi1")
    // Create an AVAsset
    let videoAsset = AVAsset(url: videoURL!)
    // Create an AVPlayerItem with asset
    let videoPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: videoAsset)
    // Initialize player with the AVPlayerItem instance.
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: videoPlayerItem)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.vdoView.bounds
    self.vdoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
}
```

And you should update your plist file to allow the contents from http: [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi)

Comment: thanku for reply, I tried your code but still got the same error :-Task <7C4E2AE9-F629-44C8-9CB8-45719FA5D76A>.<1> finished with error - code: -999

Comment: Refer here for more about the error code and fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073519/nsurlerrordomain-error-code-999-in-ios

Comment: And can you confirm, that you have set the transport security as per follows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi/32631185#32631185

Answer (score 1):

*All you need is change your code to this:

```
import AVFoundation

class your class name

var player: AVPlayer?

func playAudio() {
    guard let url = URL.init(string: "http://192.168.100.184:9050/uploads/sound/file/1/a1b19343-f785-4d48-b7d5-1abe26c03ff3.mp3" ) else { return }

    player = AVPlayer.init(url: url)
}
```

and at the end call the func in IBAction body*

just like the code below:

```
@IBAction play (sender: Any) {
playAudio()
}
```

Comment: It would be even more helpful if you can add a small description of your code.